# useEffect dependent on another useEffect being executed more than once even with dependency array. why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, use-effect

I am using two useEffects for my requriement.

1. On the first useEffect I set the latitude and longitude in state with empty dependency array.

```
   useEffect(() => { 
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo => {
           setLat(geo.coords.latitude); 
           setLng(geo.coords.longitude);
         }); 
       }, []);
```

2. On the second useEffect, I pass the latitude and longitude in an external API to fetch required data.

```
   useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(`https://someapi&lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&format=json`)
      .then(res => console.log(res.json()))
      .then(data => setData(data))
      .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
    },[lat,lng])
```

Here **my second useEffect with an API executes more than once** (although I have mentioned the lat,lng in the dependency array).  **The problem is I am allowed to make only one API request per second.**

How can I overcome this?

Comment: You could debounce/throttle the requests (in general) but, in this specific case, the second `useEffect()` is called also the first time the component is rendered (then BEFORE `lat` and `lng` have their value updated). Just check they're not empty/`undefined` (whatever you set when calling `useState()`). Side note: given that they go together you may also want to keep them in a single object: `const [coords, setCoords] = useState(); ... setCoords(geo.coords);`

Comment: Use another state variable to make sure both lat and lng exist?

Comment: I lament how common this is (one state depends on another and an API calls depends on all of them) and how poorly React handles it. Still in 2023 I just use another state variable in these situations. Set `triggerApi` or similar to `true` in your first useEffect. Make that the only element in the dependency array of a second useEffect which makes the api call if it is true. Set it to false in a function that makes the API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the comment by @AdrianoRepetti the effect runs twice: on first render and on lat/lng state change.

The possible solution might be storing previous and current states for coordinates and fetch only when there was a change. Here is the code example:

```
function YourComponent() {
  // store both current and previous states
  const [latLng, setLatLng] = useState({ lat: 0, lng: 0 });
  const [prevLatLng, setPrevLatLng] = useState({ lat: 0, lng: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((geo) => {
      // set current
      setLatLng({
        lat: geo.coords.latitude,
        lng: geo.coords.longitude,
      });
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // compare prev and current and fetch only if there was a change
    if (latLng.lat !== prevLatLng.lat || latLng.lng !== prevLatLng.lng) {
      fetch(`https://someapi&lat=${latLng.lat}&lon=${latLng.lng}&format=json`)
        .then((res) => console.log(res.json()))
        .then((data) => {
           // set prev as current
           setPrevLatLng(latLng);
           setData(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
    }
  }, [latLng, prevLatLng]);

  return <div>...</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It worked.  Now I understood how useEffect runs.

Comment: IMHO no need to store the _previous_ state. That's what dependencies in `useEffect()` are for. If initial state is `undefined` (for example) you could have your dependencies defined as `[latLong?.lat, latLong?.lng]` and `useEffect()` will take care of it for you.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Although I validate the latLong in the dependency, my component first mounts with the initial latLong state value which is zero and then re renders after the state update.  So in order to prevent this I had to put a condition inside the render as  `{(latLng.lat !== 0 && latLng.lng !== 0) && <Map center={latLng && [latLng.lat, latLng.lng]} zoom={15}>`  is this how it works?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I agree for this particular case. But for instance, if there would be some kind of subscription instead of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` the prev state would have to be stored so its just more general approach

Comment: @josh `0,0` is a perfectly valid location, no, I wouldn't use it as initial _unknown_ value. if you declare it as `const [coords, setCoords] = useState();` then inside this `useEffect()` you simply check for `if (coords) { ... }`. Note `?.` in the dependencies (and something similar when using it).

Comment: @Ros Hmmm nope, IMHO. For this particular case you do not even need `[coords.lat, coords.lng]` and you could directly go with `[coords]`. Splitting the values as single dependencies it's exactly for the subscription case (because single values won't change but the container object will). Heck, for this very specific case OP doesn't even need a second `useEffect()` and everything could/should be done inside the first one.